# Copy a variable from a for loop in another variable in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to copy a variable from a for loop ( %%i ) in another variable.
I've tried:
set temp=%%i
but when I want to use the %temp% variable I receive the error: Missing operand.
echo %%i displays my desired value.

Also I've tried:
set temp=%%~ni
but is the same error: Missing operand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Example:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F %%a in (stations.tmp) do (
  set tmp= %%a
  echo !tmp! >> stations.cfg
)
```